# Redshift non-supported correlated subquery alternative

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm not too experienced with using window functions, so I'm curious if there is an alternative way of executing the following other than doing a join:

```
SELECT se.user_id, se.session_id
FROM session_events AS se
WHERE se.session_order <
    (SELECT DISTINCT se1.session_order
     FROM session_events AS se1
     WHERE se.user_id = se1.user_id AND se1.event = 'order_completed')
```

So, the window function would be something along the lines of:

```
WINDOW_FUNCTION(session_order GREATER THAN 'x') OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY session_order DESC)
```

I realize that I could do this with a join, but looking for something more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to join, something like this

```
SELECT se.user_id, se.session_id
FROM session_events AS se
join (SELECT se1.user_id,min(se1.session_order) as session_order
     FROM session_events AS se1
     WHERE se.user_id = se1.user_id AND se1.event = 'order_completed'
     GROUP BY 1) as sel 
          on se.session_order < se1.session_order and  se.user_id = se1.user_id
```

Comment: I'm currently using something very similar to this. I'm about to check if i like this better than what I wound up doing, but the question was intended to ask, is there a window function that will conditionally pull back results within groups. Like for each partition of user_id return every session order number that is less than x (x being the subquery finding the session id where an order occured)